# C Possible overflow on casting to void pointer

Tags: c, pointers, casting, void, arithmetic-overflow

I'm working with a code analysis tool called Polyspace. I got a "possible overflow" notification on one code section and just can figure it out :)

> Error : operation [conversion from unsigned int32 to unsigned int16] on scalar overflows (results is always strictly greater than MAX UINT16)     conversion from unsigned int 32 to unsigned int 16          right:  [956448 .. 972799]

The code is:

```
typedef unsigned char       T_UBYTE;
typedef unsigned short int  T_UWORD;
typedef unsigned long int   T_ULONG;

typedef  void __far * T_EEP_ADDRESS;
..

T_EEP_ADDRESS beeeblock_GetBlockPointer(T_UWORD luw_BATAddress)
{
   T_UWORD luw_BlockPointer;
   T_EEP_ADDRESS lpul_BATEntry;
..
   luw_BlockPointer =  ( READ_EEP_32(lpul_BATEntry) & 0xFFFFuL );
..
   return (T_EEP_ADDRESS)((0x00E9800UL)+ (T_ULONG)luw_BlockPointer ); 
}
```

The line causing the error is this:

```
return (T_EEP_ADDRESS)((0x00E9800UL)+ (T_ULONG)luw_BlockPointer );
```

Any help would be extremely welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the type `T_EEP_ADDRESS` is 16 bit, and `((0x00E9800UL)+ (T_ULONG)luw_BlockPointer )` is a 32 bit-result, so you're converting a large number into a smaller one and loosing information.

What system is this on? Do you know the pointer size, since `T_EEP_ADDRESS` is a pointer?

Comment: You are right, this is an embedded system and uses a 16bit int. So it is likely the cast is affected by it :). I have to double check but my guess is you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 potential issues:

The error might be in the line above:

```
luw_BlockPointer = ( READ_EEP_32(lpul_BATEntry) & 0xFFFFuL );
sizeof(0xFFFFuL) == 8 and sizeof(luw_BlockPointer) == 2
```

Try to take the `T_ULONG` cast off as it should allow you to add an `unsigned short` to an `unsigned long` without a cast:

```
return (T_EEP_ADDRESS)((0x00E9800UL)+ luw_BlockPointer );
```